# string return by java.sql.ResultSet.getString() and its bytecode interpretation

Tags: java, string, bytecode

Consider two lines from code:

```
...
rs.next();  //rs is ResultSet interface.
rs.getString("name");
...
```

Byte code generated by **javap** is :

```
...
35:  invokeinterface #9,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/sql/ResultSet.next:()Z
   40:  pop
   41:  aload   4
   43:  ldc     #10; //String name
   45:  invokeinterface #11,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/sql/ResultSet.getString:
(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
   50:  pop
   51:  aload_2
   52:  invokeinterface #12,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/sql/Connection.close:()V

 ...
```

I am trying to interpret this bytecode.

For line `rs.getString("name");` bytecode starts from line 43 to 51.

1)At line 45 method is **INVOKED** and a string object is returned as represented by Ljava/lang/String.Is this right **OR** here, only method is being loaded from constant pool with index #11 TO STACK and executed at line 50 ???

2) where does the string object returned by `rs.getString("name");` lies? on stack or on heap as i think aload_2 is pushing some value on stack.

Actually here, i am confused in the following:

If suppose i have :

```
 ...
rs.next();
rs.getString("name");
rs.getString("name");
rs.getString("name");
rs.getString("name");
...10 more times...
...
```

and all return a same name. Then there will be 10 different string objects with same value.So it will be memory wasting and is a case for using intern(). But if these will be on stack then will it still be considered as memory wastage and need intern()???

3) I think string object returned by `rs.getString("name");` is not an interned string so definitely it will not be on Permanent Generation memory area??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the bytecode for the call

```
rs.getString("name")
```

is

```
41:  aload   4
43:  ldc     #10; //String name
45:  invokeinterface #11,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/sql/ResultSet.getString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
50:  pop
```

Taking this line one opcode at a time:

```
41:  aload   4
```

pushes the object stored in local variable #4 (`rs`) onto the stack

```
43:  ldc     #10; //String name
```

pushes the string constant `"name"` onto the stack

```
45:  invokeinterface #11,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/sql/ResultSet.getString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

pops the top 2 items off the stack to call the interface method `java/sql/ResultSet.getString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;` and pushes the result (a `Ljava/lang/String;`) onto the stack.

```
50:  pop
```

then pops the result from the previous method off of the stack.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! after poping off the results at line 50 will the result (a string object) will be garbage collected?

Comment: I have asked other question regarding my comment above at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321863/java-stack-and-object-returned-by-a-method.`