# java stack and object returned by a method

Tags: java, garbage-collection

for statement

```
rs.getString("name")  //rs is java.sql.ResultSet interface
```

bytecode is:

```
41:  aload   4
43:  ldc     #10; //String name
45:  invokeinterface #11,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/sql/ResultSet.getString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
50:  pop
```

At line 45 returned string object by `rs.getString("name")` is pushed onto stack and at line 50, return object (a string object) is poped up.

1)Does stack contain only *reference* to this returned string object with actual object on heap OR stack contains the actual String object??

2) and after poping up the returned string object, will it be garbage collected OR it's memory deallocated as stack for this method vanishes???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At line 45 returned string object by rs.getString("name") is pushed onto stack

There *is* no returned string object. There's a returned string *reference*.

Conceptually at least, *objects* are never on the stack, never returned, never passed. It's only *ever* a reference.

> and after poping up the returned string object, will it be garbage collected OR it's memory deallocated as stack for this method vanishes?

The *reference* will be cleared when the stack pops, which means that the string object itself would be eligible for garbage collection if there are no other strong references to it.

Answer (score 1):

1) The stack only contains a reference to the object. All objects are stored on the heap.

2) The storage for the string *might* be garbage collected when there is no active reference to it. This is independent from whether it's popped off the stack. This is about references to that string in the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

1. The stack has a reference to the string, not the string itself.
2. Since you're not assigning the String, the value will be GCed when the reference to the row in the ResultSet is GCed.